# Как получить значение переменной php ооп

Tags: php, ооп

Скрипт обрабатывает изображение, но я хочу еще названия каталога получить изображений.

Метод `public function imgFunc` работает норм, мне нужно тут выводить переменные `$ImageResize->previewData();` и тут выводить их по одной.

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);





class ImageResize {



    public function imgFunc($filename) {
        // тип содержимого
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

  // получение нового размера
  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
  $picWidth = 200;
  $picHeight = 200;

  $picMediumWidth = 400;
  $picMediumHeight = 400;

  $picBigWidth = 1200;
  $picBigHeight = 900;

  // загрузка
  $pic = imagecreatetruecolor($picWidth, $picHeight);
  $picMedium = imagecreatetruecolor($picMediumWidth, $picMediumHeight);
  $picBig = imagecreatetruecolor($picBigWidth, $picBigHeight);

  $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

  // изменение размера
  imagecopyresized($pic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picWidth, $picHeight, $width, $height);
  imagecopyresized($picMedium, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picMediumWidth, $picMediumHeight, $width, $height);
  imagecopyresized($picBig, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picBigWidth, $picBigHeight, $width, $height);

        $today = date("Y/m");
        $path = 'f/cat5/'.$today;

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $un =  uniqid();
  // вывод
  imagejpeg($pic, $path."/".$un."1.jpg");
  imagejpeg($picMedium, $path."/".$un."2.jpg");
  imagejpeg($picBig, $path."/".$un."3.jpg");


  $picL = $path."/".$un."1.jpg";
  $picM = $path."/".$un."2.jpg";
  $picB = $path."/".$un."3.jpg";

 // echo  $picB;

 }

 public function previewData($picB){

  echo $picL;
  echo $picM;
  echo $picB;
 }
}
$ImageResize = new ImageResize; // объявляем объект класса
$ImageResize->imgFunc('test.jpg'); // вызываем класс ВАЖНО вложить ссылку на изображение
$ImageResize->previewData(); // как получитьданные тут что бы их тут можнобыло выводить
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойства класса:

```
class ImageResize {

    private $picL,
            $picM,
            $picB;

    public function imgFunc($filename) {
        // тип содержимого
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        // получение нового размера
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $picWidth = 200;
        $picHeight = 200;

        $picMediumWidth = 400;
        $picMediumHeight = 400;

        $picBigWidth = 1200;
        $picBigHeight = 900;

        // загрузка
        $pic = imagecreatetruecolor($picWidth, $picHeight);
        $picMedium = imagecreatetruecolor($picMediumWidth, $picMediumHeight);
        $picBig = imagecreatetruecolor($picBigWidth, $picBigHeight);

        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

        // изменение размера
        imagecopyresized($pic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picWidth, $picHeight, $width, $height);
        imagecopyresized($picMedium, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picMediumWidth, $picMediumHeight, $width, $height);
        imagecopyresized($picBig, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $picBigWidth, $picBigHeight, $width, $height);

        $today = date("Y/m");
        $path = 'f/cat5/' . $today;

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        }

        $un = uniqid();
        // вывод
        imagejpeg($pic, $path . "/" . $un . "1.jpg");
        imagejpeg($picMedium, $path . "/" . $un . "2.jpg");
        imagejpeg($picBig, $path . "/" . $un . "3.jpg");


        $this->picL = $path . "/" . $un . "1.jpg";
        $this->picM = $path . "/" . $un . "2.jpg";
        $this->picB = $path . "/" . $un . "3.jpg";
    }

    public function previewData($picB) {

        echo $this->picL,
                $this->picM,
                $this->picB;
    }

}
```

Comment: а можете если не трудно объяснить, зачем это $this->picL = $path . "/" . $un . "1.jpg"; точнее $this

Comment: @Vadim,  `$this` - это псевдопеременная, ссылка на объект внутри данного класса. Пожалуйста изучите [Основы ООП](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php).